# EJS errors: not defined; can't find module 'undefined'; can't find module 'ejs'; body is not defined

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I've been very frustrated with the "Let's build twitter" node app at Chapter 2 in the O'Reilly book "Node.js Up And Running".

I've never used EJS and don't even know what extension to put for EJS files. Plus, I can't get my app working getting these various errors:

- partial is not defined
- Cannot find module 'undefined' where doing app.render('index'...
- Cannot find module 'ejs'
- body is not defined

It's even more frustrating since it's only the Chapter 2 and I'm wondering if it wouldn't be preferable to switch to another material...

Comment: Would have been impossible to answer for anyone else since you do not provide any information... :/

Comment: I'm just trying to be helpful for people like me who **are currently reading** the book and can't get their app working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you too have been frustrated with the "Let's build twitter" programming tutorial at the Chapter 2 in the O'Reilly Up and running book, here is the complement to make this "app" work.

Pre-requisites:

1. For this app to work, make sure you have a version of Express < 3.X. In fact, in version 3.0 and higher they removed the "partial" support and now is template specific. So make sure to install a version 2.x by doing so: `npm install express@2.x`
2. The book doesn't provide any information on how to use EJS files. After a bit of research, in order for express to understand and parse EJS file you have to install...ejs.
   The installation is pretty straightforward like any other module: `npm install ejs`.

The meat:

1. For this app, all the files in the folder `views` and `partials` should have the extension .ejs
2. You installed EJS but you have to tell express to use EJS as the template format in the `app.render()` function 
   You have two ways to do it:

(1) You set EJS as the default template engine and then just tell express to render your file
 `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`

`res.render('index', ...)`

(2) You just tell to the `app.render()` function to use EJS, express will take care of it

`res.render('index.ejs', ...)`

If at that point it doesn't work or it's still not clear, nothing is better than looking at working code. Fork or download the app [here](https://github.com/tinnou/twitterApp).

Hope it helps other readers.

Comment: Didn't ejs remove partial support? I seem to remember asking on the google group and they said that they did.

Comment: Well I am using express 2.5.11 and ejs 0.8.0 to be sure to use the *same* version as in the book. But in express 3.x there is no support for partials.

Comment: Handlebars supports partials with express3.  I'm using it right now.

Comment: This example is fail on the book. No instructions about how to make work, necessary modules, where to save files, and how to name them. I had to come up with a different version using mustache. Disappointment.

Answer (score 2):

Support for EJS has been removed from Express v. 3. I've built another example using Express 3 and Jade templates:

https://github.com/nosolopau/node-up-and-running-chirpie-express-3

Answer (score 1):

Install express@4 in the current project directory, it solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I was also frustrated so I built a working example - available here for download:

https://github.com/iotaweb/node-up-and-running-chirpie

Answer (score 0):

O'Reilly Book Node.js Up and Running - Part 1 => Chapter 2 Doing Interesting Things => Let's Build Twitter (working code for Express 3.0 and ejs embedded JavaScript for node renderer without partials)
download source: https://github.com/thinkphp/express-tweets

Answer (score -1):

I have installed express@4 and resolved issue.
if we write any code out side the editor and it will shows that  error.

Regards,
Ningappa